# Get the date of first day of week from week number SQL redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to get the date of Sunday/Monday (Depending on what we consider as the first day of the week) from the week number in SQL.

For example, If the week number is 10,i would like to get the date of Sunday/Monday of week 10 in a separate column. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TO_DATE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html) function with the appropriate format string, e.g. (untested)

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2023-10', 'IYYY-IW')
```

Comment: This should be `SELECT TO_DATE('2023-10', 'IYYY-IW')` to avoid error `ERROR:  invalid combination of date conventions
HINT:  Do not mix Gregorian and ISO week date conventions in a formatting 
template`